# Validating parameters on Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

When setting up parameters in Jasper Studio I cannot find a way to validate them. For example I have a string parameter but I want to ensure it is only numeric, or max length of 10, or not empty, etc. so when I try to run the report it stops me before it tries to call the SQL and shows an error instead?

I tried to use expressions and variables, and looked at scriptlets but they didn't seem to help and unless I'm searching wrong I can find nothing in the documentation or online. Surely parameter validation, even basic stuff, in a report or on the Server is a common action?

I appreciate when doing it via the API you provide your own, but when using Studio to design for the Jasper Server there must be a way to include validation simply?

thanks for any help.

Comment: This is about validating parameter on jasper server correct?, maybe you should add tag, You could ask for a parameter, validate in jrxml (expressions) if as expected use it otherwise use another one.

Comment: I found this link [configuring-input-validation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v550/configuring-input-validation) but I'm not really an expert with jasperserver, so I will leave it to you to study ;)